# Can't install cmake on Ubuntu(build error)

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cmake

I tried to install opencv(3.1.0) on Ubuntu 12.06. What does this error mean? Is observed for OpenCV modules second time? How can I fix it?

Env Var setup

```
cmake 
  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
  -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF 
  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
  -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules 
  -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON 
  -D WITH_TBB=ON 
  -D WITH_QT=ON 
  -D WITH_OPENGL=ON 
  -D BUILD_TIFF=ON 
  -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON 
  -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON 
  -D BUILD_opencv_ts=ON
```

> CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:268 (message):
>         The directory /home/user/bin/opencv/modules is observed for OpenCV
>         modules second time.
>       Call Stack (most recent call first):
>         modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)

Comment: Try with `BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF `

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already raised on [OpenCV GitHub Page](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) :

[ts module not installed](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8408)

Hope that helps.